# Button Click event fires DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged event but I don't want it

Tags: asp.net

I have two drop down lists (`ddl1` and `ddl2`) and a button.
I select a value from `ddl1` which fires the `ddl1_selectedIndexChanged` event.
When that happens, the value selected by `ddl1` goes to a database in a SELECT statement,  in which a WHERE Clause is used to fetch rows of required data.
This new data table now populates `ddl2`.
After selecting a value from `dd12`,
I press a button. 
When the button is pressed, I want to use the `ddl2_selected_value` in the `button_click` event.
The problem is when I press the button, `ddl1_selectedIndexChanged` event fires unexpectedly and binds the `ddl2` again, losing the `ddl2_selectedValue`.

```
ddl1 - EnableViewState True, PostBack = True

ddl2 - EnableViewState True, PostBack = False
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have them as 1 combined button?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have anything on Page Load that is populating the ddl1.

In that case you need to check for PostBack in the page load.

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
//Call method to populate ddl1.
//ddl1 will load only once.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by going through a couple of more blogs over net.
What I was doing was I wrote these entire set of controls in asp Panel.
The viewState property of this panel was set to False.
As soon as I changed it to true, the unwanted selectedindexchanged event got suppressed.

This got me through. :)

But, it was a hunch.
I did not yet got the reason why this happened ?

Explanations are most welcome.

@Arun: Thanks fot the concern.